# Apply capitalization of one string to another

Tags: java, performance, strings

I want to take the capitalization of one string and apply it to another.

For example: take `Apple` and `orange` and turn that into `Orange`.

This is the solution I implemented. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
public static String applyCapitalization(String to, String from) {
    int[] capArray = toCapitalizationArray(to);
    char[] charCap = from.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < capArray.length; i++) {
        if (capArray[i] == 1) {
            charCap[i] = Character.toUpperCase(charCap[i]);
        } else {
            charCap[i] = Character.toLowerCase(charCap[i]);
        }
    }
    return new String(charCap);
}
private static int[] toCapitalizationArray(String to) {
    int[] arr = new int[to.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < to.length(); i++) {
        char c = to.toCharArray()[i];
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            arr[i] = 1;
        } else {
            arr[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: What if both the strings are of different length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this in single traversal rather then two

```
for (int i = 0; i < min(apple.length(),orange.length()); i++) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(apple.toCharArray()[i]) &&
        Character.isLowercase(oranger.toCharArray()[i])){
           orange[i] = Character.toUppercase(oranger.toCharArray()[i]);
    }elseif(Character.isLowerCase(apple.toCharArray()[i]) && 
            Character.isUppercase(oranger.toCharArray()[i])){
           orange[i] = Character.toLowercase(oranger.toCharArray()[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: And some length check for safety

Comment: Updated with min(apple.length(),orange.length())

Answer (score 0):

> For example: take Apple and orange and turn that into Orange.

**I don't understand this statement**

However if you want to capitalize any string, you only have to use the replace function of the [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class

```
    public static String capitalize(String word){
    String capitalizedString = null;
    if (word != null && word.getClass() == String.class) {
            try {
             capitalizedString = word.replace(String.valueOf(word.charAt(0)), 
                              String.valueOf(word.toUpperCase().charAt(0)));
            } catch  (Exception exc) {
            System.out.print(exc);
          }
        }
       return capitalizedString;
     }
```